# "Input string was not in a correct format." when load data from Oracle in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I need to create a program, which can show data by query. Program was written in C#, data is located on Oracle.

```
OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand(sql);
cmd1.Connection = conn;
OdbcDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
DataRow dr1;

while (dr.Read())
{
    dr1 = dt.NewRow();

    for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        *dr1[i] = dr.getValue(i);*
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

`dt` is DataTable, it has 27 columns. When I running program, it shows error in `dr1[i]=dr.getValue(i)`. But I can do this query directly on the database.

It attempts to convert string to integer, value is "-3.45", I tried to check if it's number type, then convert to an integer by `int32.parse`, but did not work. And I tried to check if it's number type, then `dr1[i] = dr.getInt32(i)`, `dr.getFloat(i), dr.getDouble(i)`, `dr.getDecimal(i)`. All didn't work.

When I tried to do `dr.getFloat(i)` or `dr.getDouble(i)`, the error has changed to "Specified cast is not valid."

Please, help me, how can I fix these errors.

Comment: what's your current locale? is it something with `,` as decimal separator?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Chances are you're running into issues with the culture that your app is running in. For instance, that value might be written as -3,45 in one locale and that may be what it is expecting in this case. If possible, you can convert the string to an integer using the ```InvariantCulture``` which will give you the results you expect regardless of the culture the runtime environment is configured for.

Comment: current locale is Russia, `**,**` is using for decimal separator. You are right, maybe this is reason of that error. But how can I fix it in program? Can I set locale by code?

Comment: What is the datatype in the database? Try a `Convert.ToDouble(dr[i], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do the while loop. You can assign the Reader's data to the DataTable directly.

```
// Given a DataReader called "dr"
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Load(dr)
```

I tested this with Sqlite (SQLiteDataReader), but give it a try with Oracle (OdbcDataReader).